# Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $X \subset M$ a discrete subset.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Then, for each $x \in X$, there exists $B_x = B(x;r_x)$ such that $x \neq y \Rightarrow B_x\cap B_y = \emptyset$.

**My attempt**

For each $x\in X$, let $r_x = \inf\{ d(x,a): a\in X-\{x\}\}$.

If we suppose $r_x = 0$, then $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ $ a \in X-\{x\} : d(x,a) < \varepsilon$. Then we have $B(x;\varepsilon) \cap X \neq \{ x \}$ ,$\forall \varepsilon>0$. Thus $x$ is not isolated. But this is a contradiction since $X$ is discrete.

Thus $r_x > 0$.

Now let $x \in X$ e  $y \in X-\{x\}$. If we suppose that $\exists$ $z \in B_x\cap B_y$ , then $d(z,x) < r_x $ and $d(z,y) < r_y $. We must have $z \neq x$ e $z \neq y$, otherwise, if $z = x$:
$$d(y,z) \in\{ d(y,a): a\in X-\{y\}\} \Rightarrow r_y \leq d(y,z)$$
Which is a contradiction since $d(z,y) < r_y $. And if $z = y$:
$$d(x,z) \in\{ d(x,a): a\in X-\{x\}\} \Rightarrow r_x \leq d(x,z)$$
Which is a contradiction since $d(z,x) < r_x $. Then we have $z \neq x$ e $z \neq y$. Thus:
$$d(x,z) \in\{ d(x,a): a\in X-\{x\}\} \Rightarrow r_x \leq d(x,z)$$
and
$$d(y,z) \in\{ d(y,a): a\in X-\{y\}\} \Rightarrow r_y \leq d(y,z)$$

Which is a contradiction since $d(z,x) < r_x $ and $d(z,y) < r_y $.

Then $B_x\cap B_y = \emptyset$.

Am I right? Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **does not** work: working in the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, notice that - if we take $X=\{0, 1\}$ - then

- $r_0=1$,
- $r_1=1$, but (using your definition for $B_x$)
- ${1\over 2}\in B_0\cap B_1$, so $B_0\cap B_1\not=\emptyset$.

Your argument shows that $B_x\cap B_y\cap X=\emptyset$, but you're trying to show the stronger statement that $B_x\cap B_y=\emptyset$. (This mistake crops up at the very end, where you conclude that e.g. $d(z, x)<r_x$ is a contradiction - it's only a contradiction if $z\in X$.)

---

Fortunately, there's an easy fix - just make the radii sufficiently smaller . . .

Comment: I understand.
All I have to do is to divide $r_x$ by 2 and apply 
triangle inequality: 
$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y) <
r_x/2 + r_y/2 \leq d(x,y)$.
And this the contradiction. 
Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Santos Yes, that's exactly right. (Note that if you divide by $3$, you get the stronger property that the *closures* of distinct $B_x$s are disjoint, which is sometimes useful to have as well.)